# C++ Class template with functions from inherit parents

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Lets assume this class using C++14 (and QtRO system in origin).
https://pastebin.com/EVT4XJiz

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
 
class QTRO_1Source {
public:
    void hvEnabledChanged(bool) {};
    virtual bool hvEnabled() const = 0;
};
 
class QTRO_1SimpleSource : public QTRO_1Source {
public:
    bool hvEnabled() const override { return false; }
};
 
class QTRO_1 : public QTRO_1SimpleSource {
public:
    void write_hvEnabled(bool/*enabled*/) { }
};
 
 
template<typename ReplicaType, typename ValueType>
class ProxyProperty
{
public:
    using ReadFuncPtr = ValueType (ReplicaType::*)() const;
    using WriteFuncPtr = void (ReplicaType::*)(ValueType);
    using ChangeSigFuncPtr = void (ReplicaType::*)(ValueType);
    using UpdateHandlerFunctor = std::function<void(ValueType value)>;
    ProxyProperty(ReplicaType *replica,
                  ReadFuncPtr readFunc,
                  WriteFuncPtr writeFunc,
                  ChangeSigFuncPtr changeSignal,
                  UpdateHandlerFunctor updateHandler)
    {
        m_replica = replica;
        m_readFunc = readFunc;
        m_writeFunc = writeFunc;
        m_changeSignal = changeSignal;
        m_updateHandler = updateHandler;
    }
    template<typename T, typename HandlerT>
    void write(T value, HandlerT handler) {
        (m_replica->*m_writeFunc)(value);
    }
private:
    ReplicaType *m_replica;
    ReadFuncPtr m_readFunc;
    WriteFuncPtr m_writeFunc;
    ChangeSigFuncPtr m_changeSignal;
    UpdateHandlerFunctor m_updateHandler;
    int m_timeout{3000};
};
 
template<typename ReplicaType, typename ValueType, typename UpHandlerT>
auto createProxyProperty(ReplicaType *replica,
                         ValueType (ReplicaType::*readFunc)() const,
                         void (ReplicaType::*writeFunc)(ValueType),
                         void (ReplicaType::*changeSignal)(ValueType),
                         UpHandlerT upHandler)
{
    return std::make_unique<ProxyProperty<ReplicaType,ValueType> >(replica, readFunc, writeFunc, changeSignal, upHandler);
}
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QTRO_1 model;
//    static auto p = createProxyProperty<QTRO_1, bool>(
    static auto p = createProxyProperty(
                &model,
                &QTRO_1::hvEnabled,
                &QTRO_1::write_hvEnabled,
                &QTRO_1::hvEnabledChanged,
        [](auto val) { std::cout<< "COSTAM"; }
    );
}
```

Now, when I'm using it with first line (giving both types) - it works. When I move type deduction on compiler - I receive this error error.

> error: no matching function for call to ‘createProxyProperty(QTRO_1*,
> bool (QTRO_1SimpleSource::*)() const, void (QTRO_1::*)(bool), void
> (QTRO_1Source::*)(bool), main(int, char**)::<lambda(auto:1)>)’    76 |
> );

Yes, all 3 methods are from different class in inheritance tree (*QTRO_1* from *QTRO_1SimpleSource* from *QTRO_1Source*). I could - of course - wrap those methods in std::function.
I would like to make compiler deduce types for me.
How to do it?

PS: Added minimal reproduction code.

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReplicaType` gets deduced from 4 different arguments, and the results of deduction are conflicting. See compiler output:

> note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'ReplicaType' ('QTRO_1' vs. 'QTRO_1SimpleSource')

You can workaround it by employing 3 additional template parameter for class types in 2-4 function parameters:

```
template<typename ReplicaType, typename ValueType, typename UpHandlerT,
         class C1, class C2, class C3>
auto createProxyProperty(ReplicaType *replica,
                         ValueType (C1::*readFunc)() const,
                         void (C2::*writeFunc)(ValueType),
                         void (C3::*changeSignal)(ValueType),
                         UpHandlerT upHandler)
{
    return std::make_unique<ProxyProperty<ReplicaType,ValueType> >(replica, readFunc, writeFunc, changeSignal, upHandler);
}
```

See full example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/nWEjWv).

Comment: I came to similar conclusion. Yet, for a second I thought that there maybe other, better, more type secure solution (like dynamic_cast, but in compile time). Something that will protect and confirm that all 3 methods came from the same object.

Comment: Multipart comment [1] Methods do not belong to objects, but to classes. You pass pointers to Class member functions, there is no object here. You pass class object via the first function parameter. At this point the object (passed via the first function parameter) and the pointers to class members aren't related (aren't constrained) at all.

Comment: [2] At this point the types `ValueType (C1::*readFunc)() const` and `ValueType (ReplicaType::*readFunc)() const` might not even be compatiable. Probably you are concerned about this detail. But at the point where you instantiate `ProxyProperty` (in function body) you will get a compile time error if the types are not compatiable. The program won't compile with wrong types. But if you want to be more explicit about this, you can add some `static_assert`s (`is_base_of` or `is_convertible`), see https://godbolt.org/z/KWMhz6.

Comment: Ad [1] - yes.
Ad [2] - thank you, in *createProxyProperty* I can add this checks and should have move meaningful diagnostic in case of user errors.